# C# - .net core - Assembly which has a higher version than referenced assembly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-core, portable-class-library

I've created a .net core  class  library  which  use ADO.net technology  .
Used  library  : 
**System.Data.SqlClient version 4.4.3**  from  nuget

it works  ok  in  .netcore  console application  .  But,  when  i use  it with Xamarin forms  PCL  it occurs the following error  :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error   CS1705  Assembly 'xxx' with identity 'xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I tried  to  update System.Runtime library separately but  result is the same  .
**How to fix  this  problem  ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PCL projects rely on a selected API surface (the profile). `System.Data.SqlClient` however, according to NuGet, does not support any PCL surface but only .NET Standard and various other SDKs. Change your shared library to a .NET Standard one, and the library should work.

Comment: I want  to use  it  in  cross  platform applications  .  How  can i use it  in this case  ?

Comment: .NET Standard is basically replacing PCL. Microsoft is [recommending](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/2724) not using PCL at all.

Comment: PCL is practically replaced everywhere except in Silverlight and Windows Phone 8.x with .NET Standard. This includes all recent releases of .NET Framework, .NET Core, Mono, Unity3D, Xamarin and UWP. And considering existing practically usage of PCL (Silverlight and Xamarin) and their rapid turnover, we can expect the PCL concept to be practically dead in two or three years.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options/questions:

1. Try to consolidate the packages.
2. Do you get any warnings regarding
   this?
3. Check the Xamarin forms PCL libraries that use this package -
   and match their version. It's highly possible that they don't match versions.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if a NuGet package acting as a primary reference brings in **lower** versions of particular assemblies that are required in **higher** versions by a project referenced.

If you can't fix it with package consolidation, try adding the higher version as **a primary reference** to the project. Should the error mention a framework assembly, you'd need to add the appropriate metapackage (e.g. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`) to the project as a primary reference.